# I have a .csv file I'd like to use instead of manually entering the details to add a 'click box' to a marker point

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-maps

If I manually enter data, when I click the Google Map marker, the data appears in the box on Google Maps as I'd like.

This section is all fine.

```
import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key='AI...') 
file_name = [
    {'name': 'House A', 'location': (42.162913, 139.487541), 'price': 250},
    {'name': 'House B', 'location': (42.171569, 139.514020), 'price': 500},
]
property_locations = [house['location'] for house in file_name]
info_box_template = """
<dl>
<dt>Property Name</dt><dd>{name}</dd>
<dt>Priced from $ </dt><dd>{price}</dd>
</dl>
"""
house_info = [info_box_template.format(**house) for house in file_name]
marker_layer = gmaps.marker_layer(property_locations, info_box_content=house_info)
loc_map = gmaps.figure()
loc_map.add_layer(marker_layer)
loc_map
```

As there is a lot more data, I'd like to use a .csv with the same format above but I can't make the code work correctly. I suspect it is because when I concatenated the latitude and longitude cells from the .csv into a new column to make one cell with correct lat/long format, the dtype is 'object' so receiving the error message.

```
import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key='AI...') 
file_name = pd.read_csv('./house_data.csv')
file_name_1 = pd.DataFrame(file_name, columns= ['name', 'coordinates', 'price'])
property_locations = [house[['coordinates']] for house in file_name_1]
info_box_template = """
<dl>
<dt>Property Name</dt><dd>{name}</dd>
<dt>Priced from $ </dt><dd>{price}</dd>
</dl>
"""
house_info = [info_box_template.format(**house) for house in file_name_1]
marker_layer = gmaps.marker_layer(property_locations, info_box_content=house_info)
loc_map = gmaps.figure()
loc_map.add_layer(marker_layer)
loc_map


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-4965661a0fd7> in <module>
      3 file_name = pd.read_csv('./house_data.csv')
      4 file_name_1 = pd.DataFrame(file_name, columns= ['name','coordinates', 'price'])
----> 5 property_locations = [house[['coordinates']] for house in file_name_1]
      6 info_box_template = """
      7 <dl>
<ipython-input-46-4965661a0fd7> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 file_name = pd.read_csv('./house_data.csv')
      4 file_name_1 = pd.DataFrame(file_name, columns= ['name','coordinates', 'price'])
----> 5 property_locations = [house[['coordinates']] for house in file_name_1]
      6 info_box_template = """
      7 <dl>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is there a way to turn location data ie. 'coordinates' into integers?

Or could someone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate lat/long after creating the dataframe. Here's an example:

```
In [175]: import pandas as pd

In [176]: df = pd.read_csv(r"test.csv")

#null values for location series
In [202]: df
Out[202]:
      name  location      lat      long  price
0  house A       NaN  42.1629  139.4875    250
1  house B       NaN  42.1716  139.5140    350
```

Now concatenate lat/long and assign values to `location`:

```
In [203]: df.location = tuple(zip(df.lat, df.long))

In [204]: df
Out[204]:
      name                 location      lat      long  price
0  house A  (42.162913, 139.487541)  42.1629  139.4875    250
1  house B   (42.171569, 139.51402)  42.1716  139.5140    350
```

As [gmaps.marker_layer](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gmaps.marker_layer) accepts a list of tuples, you can get that for the `location` series like this:

```
In [199]: property_locations = df['location'].tolist()
In [200]: property_locations
Out[200]: [(42.162913, 139.487541), (42.171569, 139.51402)]
```

Now, you can use `property_locations` as an argument for `gmaps.marker_layer`.

Also, `info_box_template.format()` requires a dictionary mapping. Thus, we must transform the dataframe `df` to a list of dict's first:

```
In [19]: df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

In [20]: df_dict
Out[20]:
[{'lat': 42.162913,
  'location': (42.162913, 139.487541),
  'long': 139.487541,
  'name': 'house A',
  'price': 250},
 {'lat': 42.171569,
  'location': (42.171569, 139.51402),
  'long': 139.51402,
  'name': 'house B',
  'price': 350}]
```

Now, use `df_dict` like below to get house info for each house:

```
In [21]: house_info = [info_box_template.format(**house) for house in df_dict]
In [22]: house_info
Out[22]:
['\n<dl>\n<dt>Property Name</dt><dd>house A</dd>\n<dt>Priced from $ </dt><dd>250</dd>\n</dl>\n',
 '\n<dl>\n<dt>Property Name</dt><dd>house B</dd>\n<dt>Priced from $ </dt><dd>350</dd>\n</dl>\n']
```

Comment: thank you. When following these steps I now receive the following:
TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str. Is this occuring as I've changed property_locations from the original code to the above suggest [199]: property_locations = df['location'].tolist() ?

Comment: @jat7709, I've edited my answer to solve that issue. Hope it helps.